# Laravel 4.2 Multiple Query in date range

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to get data for each date in range from 3 tables: Main table which is connected with 2 other tables using hasMany method.

Data stored as in example:

Main Table:

```
id | article title |        url      | created_at | updated_at |
----------------------------------------------------------------
14  | Some Title    | www.example.com | TIMESTAMP  | TIMESTAMP  |
```

Views table (there is written count of views for each hour):

```
id | article_id | views | created_at | updated_at |
---------------------------------------------------
1  |     14     |  317  | TIMESTAMP  | TIMESTAMP  | (01:00:00)
2  |     14     |  186  | TIMESTAMP  | TIMESTAMP  | (02:00:00)
```

Clicks Table (there is written every click on this article):

```
id | article_id |  ip_adress  | created_at | updated_at |
---------------------------------------------------------
1  |     14     | 192.168.1.1 | TIMESTAMP  | TIMESTAMP  |
```

For example:

I need to get Articles from 01-02-2016 to 01-03-2016.
For every article I need to sum views and clicks for each day.
So in result i need to get something like this:

```
ID: 14, Title: Some Title, Views: 503, Clicks: 27
```

First, I wrote this code, but it makes lots of requests to database:

```
$dates = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $stop);

foreach ($dates as $i => $date) {
    $articles = Articles::with(['views' => function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('created_at', $date);
    }, 'clicks' => function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('created_at', $date);
    }])->get();

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
      foreach ($views->countOfViews as $i) {
        // Code
      }
      foreach ($clicks->countOfClicks as $i) {
        // Code
      }
      // Code
    }
}
```

Then I found solution, to get exact same result as I'm getting in first example, but making only three requests:

```
$dates = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $stop);
$articles = Articles::with(['views' => function ($query) use ($start, $stop) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop));
  }, 'clicks' => function ($query) use ($start, $stop) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop));
  }])->get();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    foreach ($views->countOfViews as $i) if ($date->format('Y-m-d') === $i->created_at->toDateString()) {
      // Code
    }
    foreach ($clicks->countOfClicks as $i) if ($date->format('Y-m-d') === $i->created_at->toDateString()) {
      // Code
    }
    // Code
  }
}
```

It solves problem with too many queries, but it takes to much time. Is it possible to do same thing faster?

Comment: You can do exactly what you're trying to do in your 2nd example. What's wrong with using that Method?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, but in first example I'm getting all results for each day, and in the second example i'm getting results for all days, and I need to sort them somehow by days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Code:**

```
$dates = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $stop);
$articles = Articles::with(['views' => function ($query) use ($start,         $stop) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop))
          ->groupBy('campaign_id', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
          ->selectRaw('*, sum(views) as views');
  }, 'clicks' => function ($query) use ($start, $stop) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop))
          ->groupBy('campaign_id', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
          ->selectRaw('*, sum(clicks) as clicks');
  }])->get();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    foreach ($views->countOfViews as $i) if ($date->format('Y-m-d') === $i->created_at->toDateString()) {
      // Code
    }
    foreach ($clicks->countOfClicks as $i) if ($date->format('Y-m-d') === $i->created_at->toDateString()) {
      // Code
    }
    // Code
  }
}
```